# Python TemporaryDirectory returns string when used in "with" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python TemporaryDirectory returns string when used in "with" statement

### Short Version of Question

Why does `TemporaryDirectory` return a string when used in a `with` context?

### Longer Version of Question

Here is an example of some Python code which creates a temporary directory `tempdir` and prints the corresponding object:

```py
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir="/tmp")
>>> print(tempdir)
<TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/tmpf2yh8xu9'>

>>> print(type(tempdir))
<class 'tempfile.TemporaryDirectory'>
```

As expected, `tempdir` is an instance of `TemporaryDirectory`.

And here is a similar example, where I use a `with` statement when calling `TemporaryDirectory`:

```py
>>> import tempfile
>>> with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir="/tmp") as tempdir: print(tempdir)
/tmp/tmp7mlmzegs

>>> with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir="/tmp") as tempdir: print(type(tempdir))
<class 'str'>
```

In this case, `tempdir` is a string. When I look at the `__enter__` method of the `TemporaryDirectory` class, I see the following:

```py
def __enter__(self):
    return self.name
```

Sure enough - looks like a string is returned instead of the object itself.

What accounts for this discrepancy? Why does the `__enter__` method return the file name instead of the file object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source of `tempfile.py`, in the `TemporaryDirectory` class:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self.name
```

As for the "why": The `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods control the behaviour of the class in a `with` block and apparently, the `TemporaryDirectory` class chooses to only give you the location - possibly to avoid tampering with the class and the cleanup afterwards. For example, calling `.cleanup()` before the end of the `with` block.

This would be undesirable:

```
with TemporaryDirectory('/tmp') as td:
    td.cleanup()
```

And since `TemporaryDirectory` offers no other methods beyond that, I think the design decision makes sense, although the surprise for developers is a downside. Code should not be surprising, if it can be avoided.

Comment: Yeah, my question wasn't worded well. I actually updated my question while you were writing yours. I'm definitely interested in the "why".

Comment: I think I provided my best guess at the why, which I think is fair - but I'm not sure it is accurate, there may be additional reasons.

Answer (score -1):

> Why does the **enter** method return the file name instead of the file object?

There is no discrepancy: `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` is NOT a file object.

It is simply some kind of "context manager" to represent the context within the `with`-block, which wraps a `str` storing the path created by `mkdtemp`.   There is nothing meaningful you can work with the `TemporaryDirectory` object but getting the `name`  (for which `__enter__` is returning) and `cleanup` (for which `__exit__` is invoking)

Comment: There's definitely a discrepancy between what is returned. A `TemporaryDirectory` class is not a `str`.

Comment: You missed the point: I have mentioned: "it is simply some kind of context manager".  Without `TemporaryDirectory`, you were supposed to do `d = mkdtemp()`...`_shutil.rmtree(d)`.  Within these two lines, you are just working with `d` which is a `str` storing the path.  `TemporaryDirectory` is just wrapping these two actions for you.  That's why `__enter__` is returning the `str` for you, so you are just like working with result of `mkdtemp`

Comment: `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory is NOT a file object.`
 It is though. From Python docs: "Return a file-like object. Where file-like object - A synonym for file object.". So it is literally a file object :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: @apatsekin what you quoted is under `tempfile.TemporaryFile` instead of `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`, for which it says in the doc: `This function securely creates a temporary directory using the same rules as mkdtemp(). The resulting object can be used as a context manager...`  So it is not a file object